# Python, how to recive ajax call data?

Tags: php, python, json, ajax, cgi

I'm pretty confused about python receiving ajax data...

I dont want to use flask, because I need to receive data from php file and from my website what uses 80 port.

I searched the google and found out that I can do this with cgi, but I'm not sure is this the right way to do it.

I used example and my ajax call looks like this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "brute.py",
        datatype : "json",
        data: { name: "nitin"}
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
           console.log(msg);
});
});
```

My python file **brute.py**

```
import json
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
sys.stdout.write("\n") 
sys.stdout.write("\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('name')
print(name)
```

I want to receive the data and use it for my other lines of script like:

```
url2 = "http://www.example.ee/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&token=35b276c05aa6f5eb516737a8d565eb66&submitAction=generateInvoicePDF&id_order={}".format(name) // Like this, i know for sting i use %s
```

When I click my button in the php file, I get the whole code of brute.py in console, and when I'm trying to execute my script on the terminal in just getting printed out:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

None
```

**I want to execute the script on terminal and have an loop for waiting for button to be pushed to receive data**

My question is, how can I archive this?

Comment: "I searched the google" <-- You sound like my mother! Wait... Mom, is that you?!

Comment: Yes... Son. But yeah I meant "I googled"

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that you didn't realize you can use `flask` or any other http server lib on another port such as `8080`.

So what you need to do is just start a http server at python end and then send the request to it.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "127.0.0.1:8080/xxxx", //your python end http server's router.
        datatype : "json",
        data: { name: "nitin"}
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
           console.log(msg);
});
});
```

Comment: I cant change url's port and also I cant render the page in flask, because I'm using php

Comment: @Somepub what do you mean you can't change port? You don't need to change the port at php end, just start another http server at python end on an unused port.